# VBA : Finding nested elements in HTML Document

Tags: vba

I am trying to scrape all the `href` links of products from **[this link](http://www.dell.com/vg/p/desktops.aspx?c=vg&cs=vgdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&~ck=mn)**.

I am using the following code to get the product links on the page:

```
Sub urlCatch()

Dim internet As Object
Dim internetdata As Object
Dim div_result As Object
Dim header_links As Object
Dim link, itm As Object
Dim url As String
Dim X As Variant

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
internet.Visible = True

url = "http://www.dell.com/vg/p/desktops.aspx?c=vg&cs=vgdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&~ck=mn"
internet.Navigate url

Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4
    DoEvents
Loop


Set internetdata = internet.document
Set div_result = internetdata.getelementsbyclassname("categorySubNavigation").getelementsbyclassname("c4 seriesOptions")
Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("a")
For Each itm In header_links
    Set link = itm.ChildNodes.Item(0)
    Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
Next

End Sub
```

I am getting an error at **div_reult**: "object doesn't support this property or method".

This is the first time I am using an element to retrieve something, so maybe I might be making mistakes which I am currently unaware off.

Please look into my code, and let me know what blunder I am making here.

I am told by one of my friends that I might need to use a regex to get all these links, but I wanted to get a hold of this method first.

Please give me some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Try to add an "Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()),Minute(Now()),Second(Now()) + 10)" just before "Set internetdata = internet.document" to wait 10 seconds before your set, and check if it works. If the element exists in the webpage, it's probable you don't get it because the webpage didn't load correctly yet and so you don't have it in your document when you try to scrape it

Comment: @ Matteo NNZ I tried wait time too..still its giving same error. I dont know but I have feeling I am making booboo at div_result...Maybe I am not getting it right...I just dont know why.

Comment: `internetdata.getelementsbyclassname("categorySubNavigation")` is a collection of tags ... there is only one so you can index it (no looping required) . `set div_result = internetdata.getElementsByClassName("categorySubNavigation")(0).getElementsByClassName("c4 seriesOptions")`  .... that also returns a collection, so you will have to loop `div_result(0) ... div_result(1) ... etc`

Comment: @ jsotola thanks it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetElementsByTagName` or other fetch methods work on single element and not over a collection.  You need another loop.

---

```
Sub urlCatch()

    Dim url                 As String
    Dim internet            As Object
    Dim internetdata
    Dim div_result
    Dim links
    Dim itm
    Dim itm2



    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

    url = "http://www.dell.com/vg/p/desktops.aspx?c=vg&cs=vgdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&~ck=mn"
    internet.Navigate url

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until internet.ReadyState >= 4 And Not internet.busy


    Set internetdata = internet.document.body

    Set div_result = internetdata.getelementsbyclassname("c4 seriesOptions")
    For Each itm In div_result
        Set links = itm.getElementsByTagName("A")
        For Each itm2 In links
            Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = itm2.href
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: @ cyboashu Thank you it works great. I understand the logic. Although I am self taught programmer, I find this website extremely helpful. Can you please tell me where I could find more info about web scraping, because I am pretty sure I am going to be stumbling upon many blocks on my way. Please tell me few sources where I could learn. Thanks.

Comment: You can find tutorials online. Google is the best place to search. :) by the way, I find this link quite helpful.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869680(v=vs.85).aspx